# .NET Measuring system LLC misses per second

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory

I'm interested in writing a program to measure performance data about a windows system. For measuring memory throughput, it has been suggested that counting last-level cache misses is a fast solution.  Is there a way to measure this for a computer using .NET? If not, how can it be measured with Win32? Thank you.

Comment: You are talking about the L2 Cache Misses counter, a hardware counter.  Readily available in most profilers but not easily accessible in your own code.  There's an Intel code sample that includes a device driver to allow access to the MSR register.  Not recommended.  http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor/

Comment: Thanks, I'll experiment with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You have to write a kernel mode driver to get these counters from the CPU PMC unit.